# VueJS render once into an element

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to just render once into an element?

Suppose I have a contenteditable div, and only want to render the first value, then stop rerendering as the model changes. Here only the initial value of `variable` will be rendered.

`<div contenteditable="true"> {{variable}} </div>`

Comment: *as the modal changes* ? the moment the first `keyup` happens ?

Comment: Just the initial value of the variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `v-once`

```
<div contenteditable="true" v-once> {{variable}} </div>
```

You can also wrap it with a `<span>`:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <span v-once> {{variable}} </span>
</div>
```

refs:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Cheap-Static-Components-with-v-once
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once

---

Or another solution is simply clone the `variable` and just don't modify it, for example if you call it `readOnlyVariable`:

```
<div contenteditable="true"> {{readOnlyVariable}} </div>
```

Comment: That is mainly for the components rendering, I can't put v-once on an element if it contains a lot of logic.. I just want to render the text once, not wrapped in an element.

Comment: What do you mean *if it contains a lot of logic.*? You can put `v-once` in a simple `div`; you can also wrap it with a component

Comment: So on the content-editable div I have a lot of v-on:, v-bind: etc. It is just the actual text node I want to render once, contained in the {{variable}}, not the contained element

Comment: Simply wrap it with a span `<div contenteditable="true"><span v-once>{{variable}}</span></div>`

Comment: Or just clone the `variable` to render, and don't modify the clone one

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work well with the content-editable setting. The cursor marker disappears or jumps up and down..

Comment: Please add the wrap example to the answer and I'll accept. I solved it by cloning the variable.