# Vue.js - How to pass non-reactive data to child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know we can pass data to child components via [Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html). But it is reactive in one-way data flow mode. If the value of the data is changed in **Parent component**, it also has effect (update) on `props` in **Child component**.

In my case, I don't want to get update on specific prop in **Child component** even if that data in the **Parent component** is changed. It is because **Child component** will only responsible to show the data. But the data in the **Parent Component** still has to be **reactive** in **Parent Scope**.

I've read some forum [article](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-is-it-possible-to-pass-non-reactive-resource-data-to-component/33609) that suggest to use like Json. I feel it is a little dirty way and the data in my case is just one `string`.

Is there anyways to achieve that kind of solution?

Answer (score 6):

You could copy the reactive prop in the created hook of the child component. The copy would not be reactive e.g.

```
export default {
  props: {
    reactive: Object
  },
  data: () => ({
    nonreactive: null
  }),
  created() {
    this.nonreactive = Object.assign({}, this.reactive)
  }
}
```

Note: the way you copy the reactive prop will depend on the data type, the way I've shown will work for objects.

Comment: I feel like it's necessary to mention that in your example, if that object contains a non-primitive value, modifying it will modify the prop.

Comment: May i ask you to have a look at a Vue.JS question related with the source code in github of the  book 'Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5' by Anthone Gore here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245577/laravel-vuejs-router-view-does-not-render-the-component ? Particularly take a look at the `EDIT:` section of the OP .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe u can check this one

[VueJS render once into an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247697/vuejs-render-once-into-an-element)

use `v-once` on your child component

Answer (score 2):

Use prop as data property in child component. please see the fiddle link:

[link here](https://jsfiddle.net/nehadhiman6/6zpogc4m/2/)

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
  props: ['user'],
  data:function(){
    return {
      newuser:this.user
    }
  },
  template: '<h1>hi {{ newuser }}</h1>'
});
```