# How can I set input value only once to dynamic value and then keep the modified value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

in a for loop I've an input element (type number) whose value I want to modify by a decrease and increase button:

```
<div class="s-featured-list__item s-featured-list__item--expandable" v-for="(item, itemIndex) in category.items" :key="item">
    <button class="button--decrease" @click="decreaseInput(catIndex, itemIndex)">
      <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use href="#icon-minus-16" xlink:href="#icon-minus-16"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <input class="stepper__input" :ref="'fooditem_' + catIndex + '_' + itemIndex" :value="item.min !== '' ? item.min : 1" :min="item.min !== '' ? item.min : 1" type="number" >
    <button class="button--increase" @click="increaseInput(catIndex, itemIndex)">
      <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use href="#icon-plus-16" xlink:href="#icon-plus-16"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
    </div>
```

I am setting the min attribute conditionally and also want to set the initial value of the element to the correct minimum value.

This works fine and also decreasing and increasing works fine with the following methods:

```
<script>
export default {
...
  methods: {
    decreaseInput(catIndex, itemIndex) {
      const item = this.$refs[`fooditem_${catIndex}_${itemIndex}`];
      if(item && item[0] && parseInt(item[0].min) < parseInt(item[0].value) ){
        item[0].value = item[0].value - 1;
      }
    },
    increaseInput(catIndex, itemIndex) {
      const item = this.$refs[`fooditem_${catIndex}_${itemIndex}`];
      if(item && item[0]){
        item[0].value = parseInt(item[0].value) + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My problem is, that whenever the component renders again (e.g. because I'm modifying a value or whatever), the value of the input is set back to the minimum value.

How do I set the value only once to the minimum value and then keep the modified value by the user?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable and set it value to minimum value and then whenever component render again it will set it value to its minimum value.
Hope you get what you want .

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. I want to set the value of the input element only once and not reset it to the minimum every time the component renders again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution should be using [`v-once`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-once) template directive.

---

See also [VueJS render once into an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247697/vuejs-render-once-into-an-element).

Comment: Thanks, but when I set v-once for the input element, my increase / decrease methods have no effect anymore.